# Postgresql - Join two tables, where the result has additional columns where the values are from t2

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

Two tables, t1 and t2

table: **t1**

```
id name age
-- ---- ---
1  sue   33
2  jane  25
3  ann   40
4  lucy  21
```

table: **t2**

```
id sister brother
-- ------  -------
1  sue     frank
2  sue     bob
3  jane    bill
4  ann     harry 
5  ann     dave
```

I want to **LEFT** Join t2 on t1, on name=sister, but rather than the usual output that would result from this, with multiple lines per sister where they have more than one brother, I would like the result to look like :

```
id name age brother_1 brother_2
-- ---- --- --------- --------- 
1  sue   33   frank     bob
2  jane  25   bill      
3  ann   40   harry     dave
4  lucy  21
```

Assume for the purposes of this example, that a sister never has more than 2 brothers.

I'm not quite sure how to even describe what I'm trying to do here, it 'feels' like maybe a kind of pivot ?, but I couldn't find another question/answer that matches mine, ( apologies in advance if an answer already exists on the site and I didn't spot it )

I'm using Postgresql 9.5.

Comment: could there be a third, fourth brother,....too?

Comment: For my case, the 'brothers' were limited, but I'm curious as to how this might be done if there was no limit to the 'brothers'

Comment: Because it’s not needed, I hope you don’t bother me not thinking about it anymore. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `ROW_NUMBER` along with a pivot query to handle your requirement:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.age, t2.brother,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t2.id) rn
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.name = t2.sister
)

SELECT
    id,
    name,
    age,
    MAX(brother) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) brother_1,
    MAX(brother) FILTER (WHERE rn = 2) brother_2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    id,
    name,
    age
ORDER BY
    id;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Many thanks, I got this working here with my more complicated 'real life' scenario